# How to get p5-Switch on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: perl, ubuntu, webkit

I was using ubuntu 12.04 until 12.10 was released. I used ubuntu for software development and after installing 12.10, i noticed that the perl version (5.14) shipped with 12.10 does not include the Switch.pm module needed while building WebKiT-GTK.

Looking around on the internet i found few suggestions indicating that i should install something call p5-switch from something called ports. I have looked around and was not able to get this done. I am not a perl guy and have no idea where i can get this package.

Can someone please help me as to 
1. Where to download the package for ubuntu 12.10 
2. In case it is not a .deb, How do i install it.
OR
1. At least be able to downgrade the perl installation to something lower than 5.14

Thanks and Regards 
~Sameer

Comment: Please don't use Switch - there is a reason why it was taken out of perl core.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install libswitch-perl
```

will install it for you.

"ports" is a *BSD packaging system of sorts, not what you should be looking for.

You can find what package has a particular perl module by going to packages.ubuntu.com, entering Module/Name.pm (in this case, Switch.pm) in the "Search the contents of packages" form and checking "packages that contain files whose names end with the keyword" and selecting the desired distribution, then making sure you ignore false hits like CGI/Switch.pm in the results.  Debian has the identical search for its packages at packages.debian.org.

(Note that Switch.pm has serious limitations, was never really intended to be used in production, and should certainly not be used in new code.)

Comment: Thanks for the information on packages.ubuntu.com. I had libswitch-perl already installed. But after downloading the libswitch-perl package from packages.ubuntu.com seemed to have helped. Also there was also a build fix required for webkit to build with gcc 4.6.

Answer (score 1):

Do make sure you've checked properly that there isn't the Switch module available via apt. If it is available, that's the one you want.

No, then you've two options the longer, correct way and a shorter way that's not quite as clean.

**1. Longer**

Install cpanm and perlbrew with apt. The perlbrew tool lets you install a complete version of Perl from scratch in a separate directory. Set up a user for your webkit building, run perlbrew as that user, install your perl. Then, use cpanm to install required modules and you are done. A bit of googling will get you step-by-step examples of how to use these tools. If anything goes badly wrong, you can just delete all the files in that user's home directory and start again - all you waste is a little time.

The reason experienced Perl people prefer this is that it keeps the perl you want for webkit-gtk separate from your system perl that ubuntu's packages will expect to be unchanged from the one they ship.

**2. Shorter**

Install cpanm with apt. As root, run "cpanm Switch" and it will install the Switch.pm package and any dependencies. It will also upgrade any already installed packages it thinks it needs to. This last step is why this option isn't ideal. In the (rare) case when the update isn't compatible with something else on your system uninstalling is fiddly.